# Is there a Public FTP server to test upload and download?

Tags: download, ftp, upload

What I want to do is measure broadband speed using c#.

To do this, I use `NetworkInterface.BytesReceived` and `BytesSent` to get the current amount of bytes sent and received from my network adapter and get the `DateTime`.

Then I download/upload a file and get the `BytesReceived`/`BytesSent` and `DateTime` again. The download/upload speed is just the the difference between the `BytesReceived`/`BytesSent` divided by the time difference.

Now I am wondering if there is a public FTP server where I can download and upload files.

Comment: you can use [mmnt.net](https://www.mmnt.net) to find any free server (ftp, etc...) – [Daniel I. Cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6446244/daniel-i-cruz) 

An useful comment below

Answer (score 195):

Tele2 provides ftp://speedtest.tele2.net , you can log in as anonymous and upload anything to test your upload speed. For download testing they provide fixed size files, you can choose which fits best to your test.

You can connect with username of *anonymous* and any password (e.g. *anonymous* ).
You can upload files to *upload* folder. You can't create new folder here.
Your file is deleted immediately after successful upload.

Found here: http://speedtest.tele2.net/

Comment: Note:  The upload folder appears to automatically purge any file that is uploaded.

Comment: @John M Of course it would, what else would you expect it to do?

Comment: Does not allow directory creation.

Comment: @John As long as it's not purged immediately after uploading, it's good enough for testing purposes.

Comment: How do we connect to this. I am using these credentials. ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp://speedtest.tele2.net', 'anonymous').

Answer (score 85):

Try `ftp://test.rebex.net/`

It is read-only used for testing Rebex components to list directory and download.
Allows also to test FTP/SSL and IMAP.

Username is "demo", password is "password"

See https://test.rebex.net/ for more information.

Comment: Either this site is not working anymore; or this is an attempt to promoting a site.  I see no ftp pages provided by this site.

Comment: It works. You need to the correct protocol instead of HTTP.

Comment: Example: FTP://test.....

Comment: It asks me for a username and password.

Comment: click the first link for the username/password

Comment: username is demo password is password ftp is test.rebex.net

Comment: As of October 2018, this allows uploading and downloading. The uploaded files are kept for 30 minutes

Answer (score 61):

Currently, the link [dlptest](https://dlptest.com/ftp-test/) is working fine.

The files will only be stored for 30 minutes before being deleted.

Comment: Fine to me. Thsnk you.

Comment: As of May 13, 2021, works like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: not working anymore :(

Comment: works well in 2023

Comment: Kinda works in 2023, from command line FTP not C#

Comment: For me file is not uploading but can connect from java code base

Answer (score 10):

There's lots of FTP sites you can get into with the 'anonymous' account and download, but a 'public' site that allows anonymous uploads would be utterly swamped with pr0n and warez in short order.

It's easy enough to set up your own FTP server for testing uploads. There's plenty of them for most any desktop OS. There's one built into IIS, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an FTP server and its working. I was successfully able to upload a file to this FTP server and then see file created by hitting same url. Visit [here](https://www.swfwmd.state.fl.us/data/ftp/) and read properly before use. Good luck...!

Edit: link is now dead, but the FTP server is still up! Connect with the username "anonymous" and an email address as a password: ftp://ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us

**BUT FIRST** read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171201224411if_/http://ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us:80/pub/README.txt) before using it

Comment: Link is dead as of Sept 2017.

Comment: The link is live as of Sept 2017

Comment: Link is dead as of 1519036935.