# Python ftplib connection error (gaierror)

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to make a very basic FTP client in python, and within the first few lines of code I have already run into a problem

My Code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.mysite.com')
```

With this code, and with countless different urls used, I will always get the same error:

```
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this means that your computer can't resolve the domain name that you gave it. A detailed error description is available [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror). Try to use a well-known working FTP to test (e.g. `ftp.microsoft.com`). Then try to open the FTP you're trying to access with some FTP client.

Comment: Thank you! I was sure that I had tested well working domain names before but apparently not.

Comment: This is good advice, but the Microsoft ftp URL is outdated. This stackoverflow Q&A has a alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968703/is-there-a-public-ftp-server-to-test-upload-and-download

Answer (score 26):

I found myself here with this error trying to connect using the full path rather than just the hostname. Make sure you split that out and use `cwd(path)` after `login()`.

For example:

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('pub/data/noaa/2013')
```

**instead** of:

```
# Doesn't work!!
ftp = FTP('ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('2013')
```

Kind of obvious in hindsight, but hopefully I help you notice your simple mistake!